# Is there a genuine code snippet that I can use for escaping http response against XSS attacks?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, xss

I want to encode(html entity and html attribute) all the responses against XSS attacks and don't want to implement my own since I am not so familiar to escaping techniques. 
Is there a code snippet mvc middleware or filter or even maybe formatter that I can use in asp.net core-mvc ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET Core uses the new encoders contained in the `System.Text.Encodings.Web` package.

To HTML-encode a string, you can use the default instance:

```
var encodedValue = HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode("value to encode")
```

Alternatively, you can also resolve `HtmlEncoder` via dependency injection if you don't like the static property.

Comment: yeah I've seen this but I actually need a full snippet which demonstrates which parts of the response to encode should I encode responsebody , headers and also should I encode against JS and CSS too ?

Comment: If you encode your whole response, your site is very unlikely to work correctly. In general, you only encode individual string values that are potentially provided by the user.

Comment: It's also worth noting that if you use Razor, values are automatically and transparently HTML-encoded when you use `@` (e.g `@Model.FirstName`).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!